# How to force a svg animation to retrigger in a mask

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, mask

I am trying to use CSS and SVG mask to create animation.

The animation seems to be working the first time the svg is loaded (first time I apply the mask, but if I remove it and apply it back, it does not trigger again.
Even worth, when my SVG is loaded from cache, it seems to never trigger.

Here is a simple example : https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-animated-mask-qebii?file=/index.html

But I am having this problem in an amp project, so JS is likely not a option.

Comment: retrigger based on what? masks cannot be interactive i.e. you can have a continuous animation only, you can't trigger the animation based on the user doing something. This applies even if JS was an option. You could of course generate a new mask each time but that would require JS.

Comment: Note if you had your mask inline rather than just referenced by CSS then you can get interactivity because the animation will then run in your main document.

Comment: Ok seems to be the answer I needed, unfortunatly not the one I wanted ^^'

I was hoping to find a way to retrigger then animation by removing and re applying the mask in the css (with a dynamic selector for exemple).